# A floating button fixed at the bottom of UITableview with scrollViewDidScroll not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using this piece of code to make a UIButton floating fixed at
bottom of the UITable, but initially the UIButton will append exactly below
the last cell of the UITableView, only when I scroll the page the UIButton will 
get to the bottom, what can I do to make the button come to the bottom at first?
Thanks in advance!

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        CGRect frame = self.chatButtonView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.chatButtonView.frame.size.height;
        self.chatButtonView.frame = frame;

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.chatButtonView];
    }
```

Comment: As per your requirement you should add button to the footerView of UITableView

Comment: I called this piece of code on viewdidload but also did the same thing, not sure why:-(void) setUpChatButton {
    CGRect frame = self.chatButtonView.frame;
    float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    frame.origin.y = height - self.chatButtonView.frame.size.height;
    self.chatButtonView.frame = frame;
    
//    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.chatButtonView];
    [self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview: self.chatButtonView];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, i have added floating button in tableview, same way you can add any other control.

```
// Create button in `ViewDidLoad` and add to tableview.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // *** Creat a button, calculate Y position at bottom of table, assign frame & add to tableview ***
    _btnFloating = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGFloat yPos = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(_btnFloating.bounds);
    [_btnFloating setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
    [self.tableView addSubview:_btnFloating];

    // *** Adjust Inset and scroll indicator of tableview ***
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(_btnFloating.bounds), 0.0);
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(_btnFloating.bounds), 0.0);

    // *** Add observer on tableview frame change to update floating button frame ***
    [self.tableView addObserver:self
                     forKeyPath:@"frame"
                        options:0
                        context:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - KVO
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
        [self adjustFloatingViewFrame];
    }
}

- (void)adjustFloatingViewFrame
{
    CGRect newFrame = _btnFloating.frame;

    newFrame.origin.x = 0;
    newFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(_btnFloating.bounds);

    _btnFloating.frame = newFrame;

    [self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:_btnFloating];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self adjustFloatingViewFrame];
}

// Don't forget to remove Observer on Tableview otherwise it will lead to crash.
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.tableView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}
```

Comment: There is great Magic of these piece of code, the layout seems to be fine, the button is now happy to stay at the bottom, but when I pop that uitableview, the APP crashes, and here is the error message:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x14085d200 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:

Comment: @CodeFarmer i have updated my answer and added `dealloc` method to remove observer, Add `dealloc` method and code snippet from answer to your code. Happy coding :)

Comment: Love life, love coding, love stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
  UIButton *chatBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
[chatBtn setTitle:@"Chat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[chatBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

[chatBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(chatbuttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  //chatbuttonClick is method that handle button's action

self.myTableView.tableFooterView = chatBtn;
```

There is no need to change frame in `scrollViewDidScroll`. You have to set `tableFooterView` instead of adding `subview` to it.

Comment: Actually I have also tried tableFooterView, but the button is still append exactly below the last cell of the UITableView instead of the bottom of the screen, is details that I have dismissed?

Comment: Yes, I just want to let it floating at the bottom of the screen permanently

Comment: then it is very simple. Add button yo your view (i.e `self.view`) and button frame should be `(0,self.view.frame.size.height - 30,self.view.frame.size.width,30)`

Comment: I tried you new solution, but it stay at the bottom of all the cells instead of bottom of the "screen", in this case, if I scroll the tableview, the button is also move with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this question is by using a container view, which may be more clear to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Using `addChildViewController` make tableView above.